# animateWithDuration and touchesBegan don't work in pair

Tags: ios

I need to handle touch on my object when it move across my screen. When touchesBegan called I need to hide my object.

this is my code in UIViewController:

```
- (void)win {
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rocket_%d.png", i]]];
        imageView.tag = 1000;
        CGSize size = imageView.image.size;
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(200 + (i * 60), 500, size.width, size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        [rockets addObject:imageView];
        [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    [self startRockets];
}

- (void)startRockets {

    CGFloat timeInterval = 1.0;
    for (UIImageView *imageView in rockets)  {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:timeInterval options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
        } completion:nil];
        timeInterval += 1.0;
    }


}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSArray *views = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView *v in views) {
        if (v.tag == 1000) {
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(v.frame, touchLocation) == YES) {
                [v setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you are missing the AllowAnimatedContent. Try changing your

`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`

to

`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent`

---

...another way might be to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` :

```
- (void)createViews {
    rockets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        UIView *view = [UIView new];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        view.frame = CGRectMake((i * 60), 100, 50, 50);

        UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rocketTouched:)];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        [self.view addSubview:view];
        [rockets addObject:view];
    }
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(moveViews) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void)moveViews {
    for (UIView * view in rockets)  {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{
            view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x -10, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
- (void)rocketTouched:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap {
    tap.view.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: i have added this but it does not help me. I think the problem is in the thread. Because the method for animation grab my object and I can't handle it in the main thread

Comment: I actually would recommend using `UITapGestureRecognizer` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need also check this if you need to detect intersection with object.

I have edited touchesBegan method and it works.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    for (UIImageView *imageView in rockets) {
        CALayer *bbl1ObjPresentationLayer = (CALayer*)[imageView.layer presentationLayer];
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(bbl1ObjPresentationLayer.frame, CGRectMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y, 1, 1))) {
            NSLog(@"intersect");
                //They are intersecting
            }
}
}
```

if you do it using CALayer insted of UIImageView object this work correct. Check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642947/how-to-find-whether-two-objects-intersect-each-other)