# How to make my custom gesture recognizer class instances work simultaneously?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, uigesturerecognizer

You can download code example from this libk:
https://github.com/mriddi/ExempleCustomGestureRecognizer.git

I create my cusom gesture recognizer class like this:

```
@protocol MyGestureRecognizerDelegate <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@optional
-(void) willDo;
@end

@interface MyGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
{
    …
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyGestureRecognizerDelegate> delegate;
…
@end

@implementation MyGestureRecognizer
@synthesize delegate;
…
-(void) call{
    [delegate willDo];
}
…
@end
```

My ViewController adopt `MyGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.
In `ViewController` I create instances of my class:

```
MyGestureRecognizer * grFerst;
MyGestureRecognizer * grSecond;
grFerst.delegate=self;
grLeft.delegate=self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: grFerst];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: grSecond];
```

I want to make both gesture recognizers instances to work simultaneously.
I try to add to my `ViewController` method

[shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

but this method never calls, I checked it using `NSLog` function.

Please help me solve this problem (allow work both gesture recognizers simultaneously).

Comment: Why do you need a delegate? Maybe have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431806/animatewithduration-and-touchesbegan-dont-work-in-pair/13432038#13432038

Comment: No, i need delegate. My program has 2 control wheels (one wheel is responsible for move cursor on x, the other one - move cursor y axe). It is kind of painting app. Each wheel has it's own gesture recognizer. When i rotate wheel, gesture recognizer handle the angle and transmit it to it's delegate. Next, delegate convert recived angle to point... I meen that my custom gesure recognizer need in it's own protocol and delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should allocate the Gestures

```
MyGestureRecognizer * gesture = [[MyGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
gesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Or you could use the control wheel as the target and do all your angle calculations in there. Then you delegate back to the mainViewController.

Comment: Oops... i forgot say that i have my custom init method (it calls super init too). But using target can't help me becose i can only call target's method, and can't send parapeters to it.

Comment: I have created code exeple on github : https://github.com/mriddi/ExempleCustomGestureRecognizer.git

Comment: You could use the control wheel as the target and do all your angle calculations in there. Then you delegate back to the mainViewController.