# how to touch on animated object iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

For animation my `UIImageView` object I use these approaches:

- Block animation
- Begin/Commit method for animation `UIView` based object

The problem is next: When I try to tap on some object on my view it does not response to my action. Being animatable the object don't receive any calls from the main thread.

In my UIViewController I have method below that should handle touched object. All objects receive touch events but the objects which are using in animation block don't receive any events.

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Anybody knows what is the probem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for an animated view to recieve user events, `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` must be passed into the options parameter.

Comment: yse I have added this, but it does not help me. When I tap on object the object recieve my action in touchesBegan method, but the frame of touched object has the value that I set in animation block not the current frame. For example it moves from origin.y = 500 to origin.y = 0. I touch on object when it has origin.y = 250 and check this value in touchesBegan, but i see here origin.y = 0 istead origin.y = 250. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: as I think I have the smae problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642947/how-to-find-whether-two-objects-intersect-each-other

Comment: Because core animation ***Does Not Animate The Object***.  Core animation creates a decoy and animates that.